# Is that possible show user's post after user login

Tags: user-registration

I have website, Administrator setup one post for each register user, only this user can see it when he/she login.(the author of the post is the user's name). I think when user login just search user name equal to author name will be fine.

The question is how to do it, I don't know too much about PHP, Hard to make it work.

He is some code, maybe useful.

```
  <?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
```

Comment: How do you save the post for a particular registered user?

Comment: Just edit it. The author of the post is the user's name

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current user ID with [`get_current_user_id( )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id):

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id( );
```

The user ID can be used to get the userdata with [`get_userdata( )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata):

```
$user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );
```

With that information you should be able to fetch the requested Post with `WP_Query`.
For example (by users nicename):

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'author_name=rami' );
```

Combining this all together you can create something like:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in( ) ) {
  $user_id = get_current_user_id( );
  $user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );

  $query = new WP_Query( 'author_name=' . $user_data->user_nicename );

  if( $query->have_posts( ) ) {
    while( $query->have_posts( ) ) {
      $query->the_post( );

      // The Loop
    }
  }
} else {
  // A visitor
}
```

You can play a little bit with the code to get exactly one post with `WP_Query` but you sure are a bit further down the road with this.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider searching by user_id, and not user nicename. User can change his nicename, so you would have to sync it (update user's page everytime user changes his nicename).

Selecting by nicename is also much slower than selecting by user id.

Use

```
$query = new WP_Query( array('author'=>$user_id, ...<OTHER QUERY PARAMS YOU ALREADY USE>) );
```

Of course you should also take care of not showing this post/page to other users.